# Does getting reputation via Documentation help lifting a question ban?

Tags: discussion, support, documentation, reputation, post-ban

It all started when I was a beginner in programming, I did all kinds of bizarre things until I got suspended from SO, I was no longer able to ask questions anymore.

It was like this for years, and since the launch of Documentation, I got nearly 100 reputation (and actually I got much more than that since I was banned), and the suspension persists.

So my question is, does getting reputation via Documentation actually contributes to lifting the ban or not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It *can*. It's not a particularly efficient way to get out of a post ban, but - just as with edits on normal posts - edits to Docs do count as positive contributions to the site. I've known a few people to "work their way out" by editing; it usually takes them a few months, but they learn a lot in the process.

Otherwise, the standard advice for lifting a post-ban applies: [**fix your existing posts!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: I should also note that multiple people have been suspended for plagiarism already, so if anyone reading this is thinking that copying some good answers or blog posts would be a quick and effective way around a q-ban... It's neither.

Answer (score 7):

You were question banned. Your ability to create documentation means nothing as far as your ability to ask good questions is concerned.

So if it does contribute to lifting your question ban, it *shouldn't.*

Comment: Well they're relevant, because being able to write *good* documentation means one is actually able to describe *something* in a code in a meaningful way.

Comment: @Servy That was harsh. SO already mentioned that it discourages copy-pasting from any other external documentation. While this applies to some users, it doesn't apply to me.

Comment: @OverCoder It applies to a large portion of the contributions, so that someone contributed to documentation doesn't mean what you claimed, that the person is able to make meaningful descriptions of programming concepts; it is just as likely to mean that they learned how to copy-paste from somewhere else.  It's not a commentary on your specific contributions either way.